# How do you make a .ics calendar file so it can be subscribed to? (not just add to calendar)

Tags: php, icalendar

I've published a .ics calendar file which users can add to their calendar. What syntax do I use when I present it so that users can "subscribe" to it where updates will automatically propagate? (The .ics URL automatically updates)

Comment: I assume you mean that the URL is fixed and the content updates?

Comment: Correct. So it's as simple as just ensuring LAST-MODIFIED is updated (think I generate that on the fly on the static URL).

Answer (score 3):

The calendar software will update it regularly and updating accordingly using the data found in the new calendar file. The URL won't change, only the content of your file as says by jeroen.

> Property Name: LAST-MODIFIED
>
> Purpose: The property specifies the date and time that the
>   information associated with the calendar component was last revised
>   in the calendar store.

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2445.txt

Comment: So there's no difference between add to calendar and subscribe? - just on the back end the LAST-MODIFIED has to be updated (which it is).